# Getting npm Err! tar.unpack while setting up cordova environment

Tags: yeoman-generator-angular

I followed this tutorial to install yeoman, bower, grunt to setup angularjs corodva project. http://www.sitepoint.com/kickstart-your-angularjs-development-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/

as it says i installed everything but still it gives me error! while creating angular project.

I did,
My PC is running windows 8.1 64 bit

1. Install node.js using windows installer (64 bit)
2. Install git (selected windows commandline instead git bash while installing)
3. npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower

I cross checked everything whether it is installed

```
     C:\Windows\system32>yo --version && grunt --version && bower --version
     yo - 1.4.7
     grunt-cli v0.1.13
     bower - 1.4.1
```

4. npm install -g generator-angular

5. created a dir in c and installed yo angular

   ```
   C:\test\yo angular
   ```

It asked for sass (i given NO), bootstrap (YES), other angularjs library (NO) then it started installing

then after sometime, it asks that my package.json should overwrite  i gave yes

after the few files generated then shows ERR!

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/wrappy/1.0.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/wrappy/1.0.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/brace-expansion/1.1.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/delayed-stream/0.0.5/package.tgz
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing form-data@0.1.4
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /root/.npm/is-property/1.0.2/package.tgz
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing request@2.54.0
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: Yes, i double checked whether everything is installed.. When angular asks for overwrite package.json, don't give yes, just give no... So it installs everything correctly.. It worked for me...

Comment: :) thanks it worked for me too. you should add your comment as a answer for future coders

Comment: i cannot add buddy, u make it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Prasanth says, The best way is to do the following:

- npm cache clean
- double checked whether everything is installed
- also try close then re-open cmd as administrator
- When angular asks for overwrite package.json, Say `n` to all

Still faces issue, then try this

- make sure Grunt is installed
- npm install (it will install missing packages)